# GET request with "hink" in the header

Tags: php, http

I'm experiencing some weird issues on my web server, so i look upon my apache log and found several strange entries, from different IP most of which from china. The request is this one:

```
"GET /index.php?s=/index/ hink" 400 226 "-" "-"
```

Can someone tell me which kind of vulnerability they're trying to use? thanks

Comment: https://securitynews.sonicwall.com/xmlpost/thinkphp-remote-code-execution-rce-bug-is-actively-being-exploited/ - install ModSecurity (https://modsecurity.org/)

Comment: Searching this exact string yields tons of results.

Comment: But the ton of results refers to thinkphp, this is different i think